# Is it possible to determine the window/application with focus from a bat script?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, rundll32

The function to do so is apparently in User32.dll. I've been trying to tinker with rundll32.exe, but when I run this:

```
rundll32 User32.dll,GetActiveWindow
```

It exits without error but does nothing. The exit code will of course only say whether or not there were errors running rundll32.

Is there a bat scripting trick to retrieve that value and stuff it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

The Window API functions are not designed to be called like that from DOS.  You need to create a console application that runs minimized.  It can call the `GetActiveWindow()` function and write the application title out to STDOUT.  Then you can assign that value to an environment variable in the batch file like this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('start /wait /min YourCustomApp.exe') do set somevar=%%i
echo The active program is "!somevar!".
endlocal
```

The `/wait /min` make the batch file wait until your app has terminated before trying to assign the value on STDOUT to `somevar`.  I like to use `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` whenever I assign an environment variable in a batch file and then use it later in the same batch file.

Comment: I already know they're not designed to be called like that... it's not a real operating system. But it's what I have to work with. Is there a workaround short of compiling another exe in Visual Studio?

Comment: I can't think of any way to have DOS call any Windows API calls and trap the returned data, short of creating a console application.  You might search for a way to do it with a `.vbs` script.  I searched a little, but everything seems to require a DynamicWrapper DLL (I think DynWrap.dll).